# Trying to rename a folder in extSdCard in my android device using code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop and application with 2 buttons (Show,Hide) when i click show it rename a folder from .pics to pics

and for hide button is to rename from pics to .pics and also run media scanner on every click.

here is the code i dont know where is my error, i made alot of searches in here but non solved my problem

```
Button btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

//rename the folder vids
String sdcard = new String("/storage/sdcard1/");
File from = new File(sdcard, (".pics"));
File to = new File(sdcard, ("pics"));
from.renameTo(to);

//create on click to trigger media scan
btnShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Broadcast the Media Scanner Intent to trigger it
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        //send a message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media scanner triggered....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

i specified the path of the extSdCard before using Environment will show the normal sdcard and not the external SD.

When i run it on my phone i only get the media scanner triggered, and the folder do not get renamed.

Thanks

Comment: what is happening now? any errors? logcat please

Comment: `from.renameTo(to);` returns a `boolean`, `true` on success, `false` if it failed. Check what the result is. `/storage/sdcard1/.vids` could be the wrong path

Comment: Why the parens around "vids"? Does this even compile?

Comment: Expanding on what zapl said, your code could benefit from a few log statements here. Or you could run your app under a debugger. I'm guessing zapl is right; what do **from.toString()** and **from.exists()** return?

Comment: help please, still didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need following permission to make changes on SD card

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I added the permission in the manifast, i added the boolean and i get false, this is what i added, boolean succeeded = from.renameTo(to);
  System.out.println("File rename:"+ succeeded); and the output is File rename:false